# How do you add products to Squarespace with the API?

Tags: squarespace

A friend of mine has asked me to connect their product database with their Squarespace website.
However I cannot find any API calls that allow me to add products or get products from the website.

What I would like to do:

- POST all the products to Squarespace from an external database
- GET notified (webhook) when a product is sold
- PUT (update) a product when it has been sold on the website, or somewhere else.

Any links or advice where to find this info would be awesome! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the limitations may be surprising, the [Squarespace developer docs](https://developers.squarespace.com/commerce-api) are correct on this:

> With the Squarespace Commerce API, you can build applications that
>   manage data from your Squarespace store. HTTP endpoints are provided
>   which allow you to:
>
> - Retrieve orders
> - Update orders with fulfillment information

At time of writing, that's all you can do with the API. So **it is not currently possible to add products, receive purchase notifications, nor update a product's status.**.

As to receiving purchase notifications, all you could do is retrieve order info on a schedule of some kind and compare to the last set of data in order to discover new orders, which doesn't really count as a good solution in my opinion, but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Thanks. It's what I was thinking, however I was hoping I was missing something. :)